# Making apostrophes render correctly in perldoc

Tags: perl, perldoc

I can't figure out how to get apostrophes displaying correctly in my Perl documentation. For example, the text `'test'` displays as `âtestâ`.

- `E<39>` also renders as `â`

  - also `I<'>`
  - also `S<'>`
  - also `E<apos>`
- `C<'>` renders as `"'"` (so apparently the terminal isn't the problem)
- `F<'>` renders as underlined `â`

I've also tried running `perldoc` with `-T`, `-n nroff` and `-n troff` but none made a difference. Running with `-t` fixed the apostrophe problem but also kills all other text attributes.

I've been putting up with this for a while, but it's really starting to irritate me. How can I get them displayed correctly?

Comment: The problem is that perldoc is based on `nroff`, and these characters do not map to themselves. In nroff, you can use ``\`` as replacement to get these characters. See [perldoc renders incorrectly](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=431041)

Answer (score 0):

@hwnd's [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=431041) led me to the `LANG` environment variable. By changing it from `en_US.UTF-8` to `en_US` I can get the perldocs displaying correctly. Not sure if this will cause problems elsewhere but so far I haven't run into any.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing as well. As stated elsewhere, the issue is the discrepancy in encoding of certain characters and the various programs perldoc uses to format and render the pod.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade [Pod::Perldoc](http://p3rl.org/Pod%3a%3aPerldoc) and use the `-o term` backend.

Answer (score 0):

can't say i know lots about this issue, but this has worked for me in the past when characters don't appear correctly:

`binmode(STDOUT, "utf-8");`